# Is there a CalendarView equivalent in flutter?

Tags: android, flutter

I'm building a flutter port of an app I made in standard Android code, and it heavily relies on a `CalendarView` to keep its ease of use. Is there a flutter Material widget similar to a `CalendarView` in Android?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it does. By calling the modal [`showDatePicker()`](https://api.flutter.dev/flutter/material/showDatePicker.html) it will let you pick a date just like a `CalendarView` and return a `DateTime` object.

```
DateTime date = await showDatePicker(
              context: context,
              firstDate: firstDate,
              initialDate: initialDate,
              lastDate: lastDate,
            );
```